# Dividing a group of 288 students into 16 subgroups (not randomly), dividing each subgroup into 6 sub-subgroups and calculating a probability.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $288$ students which are divided into $16$ groups of $18$ each. This division is not random. Within each group, further sub-groups are created, say $A, B, C, D, E$ and $F$, containing $3$ students each randomly. Name these larger groups "lab-groups" and these smaller groups "homework pods". Now all the students are further divided into $72$ groups of $4$ students each irrespective of their lab-groups, again randomly. Name these groups "report pods".

The question is: What is the expected number of report pods that have only students in them which were in a homework pod denoted by the same letter without any two of them being from the same lab group?

I have two approaches to this question and both of them seems right to me but both give different answers:

**1. First Approach:**

First, we will calculate the probability that a randomly selected report pod
has only students in them which were in a homework pod denoted by the same
letter without any two of them being from the same lab.

The total number of ways we can create such a report pod is ${288\choose4}\cdot16^4$.
This is because we must choose $4$ students out of $288$ and we must assign them
in a lab group, which can be done in $16^4$ ways as each student can be from any of
the $16$ labs.

The favourable number of ways is ${16\choose4}\cdot4!\cdot{48\choose4}\cdot6$.
This is because we must choose $4$ labs from $16$ labs and assign them to $4$ students.
This is done in ${16\choose4}\cdot4!$ ways. Also, we must choose $4$ students with
the same homework pod letter, and there are $48$ of them, and since there are $6$ such
letters, we have to multiply by $6$.

So, the required probability is $\frac{{{16\choose4}\cdot4!\cdot{48\choose4}\cdot6}}{{288\choose4}\cdot16^4}\approx0.0028$.

So, the expected number of report pods that have only students in them which were in a
homework pod denoted by the same letter without any two of them being from the same lab
is $72\times\frac{{{16\choose4}\cdot4!\cdot{48\choose4}\cdot6}}{{288\choose4}\cdot16^4}\approx 0.19957$.

**2. Second Approach:**

This one is simpler than the one above but gives a drastically different answer. Suppose I have to create a report pod. This can be done in $288 \choose 4$ ways. Also, the favourable number of ways can be $6\times 48\times\ 45\times\ 42\times 39$. This is because we need to choose a letter out of $6$ letters. There are $48$ students in each letter, and we choose any one in $48$ ways. Now, there are $2$ other students in the same lab group as the student chosen. So, we can only choose a student from $45$ remaining students since we don’t want any student to be in the same lab group. Similarly, then there are $42$ students to choose from and then $39$.

So, the required probability is $\frac{6\times 48\times\ 45\times\ 42\times 39}{288 \choose 4}$. So, the expected number of report pods is $72\times \frac{6\times 48\times\ 45\times\ 42\times 39}{288 \choose 4}\approx 5.4447$.

Can anyone please help me which of the two approaches are correct, if any, and if not, what are the mistakes? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry for that!

Comment: Both probabilities calculations are not quite right. To fix the second, you need to divide by $4!$. This makes it numerically close to the first, but not exactly equal to it. I don't understand your first method well enough to say exactly what goes wrong

Comment: The bigger issue is that I don't see a justification for multiplying the probability that a group has the desired property by the number of groups to obtain the expected number of groups with the desired property.  Since the probability is small, this is likely a decent approximation to the expected value, but I don't see why it should be exact.

Comment: That's easy to answer. For each report pod you can just define $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_{72}$ to be Bernoulli random variables that take $1$ if the conditions are met and $0$ otherwise. Then the expectation of sum is just sum of expectations, which is just equal to $72\times Pr(X_1=1)$

Comment: Okay, I see that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a comment that it doesn't matter whether the lab groups or homework pods are formed randomly or not, since the report pods are formed randomly.

We can think of making a table with $6$ rows for the letters and $16$ columns for the lab groups. Each cell of the table contains $3$ students. As you note, a single report pod can be formed in $\binom{288}{4}$ ways. A favorable report pod is one where all members come from the same row of the table, but no two members come from the same column. To form a favorable report pod, we can therefore choose a letter ($6$ ways), choose four columns ($\binom{16}{4}$ ways), and then, for each of those columns, choose one member from that column and the chosen row ($3^4$ ways). Hence the probability that a report pod is favorable is
$$
\frac{6\cdot\binom{16}{4}\cdot3^4}{\binom{288}{4}}.
$$

This is smaller, by a factor of $4!$, then the number given by your method 2 because you are counting each report pod multiple times, one for each ordering of the members.

It is close to the answer given by your method 1, which can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{6\cdot\binom{16}{4}\cdot\frac{48}{16}\frac{47}{16}\frac{46}{16}\frac{45}{16}}{\binom{288}{4}}.
$$
But I couldn't quite follow your method 1--in particular I couldn't see why you could choose the homework pod members independently of the lab assignments--so I can't pinpoint any particular flaw that would explain why it leads to a different answer.

Comment: Think out loud for a minute, the denominator in your method 1 already seems problematic since the outcomes it enumerates should not all be weighted equally. For example, if the four members are assigned the same lab group then the $284$ other people in the class have to be partitioned into $15$ lab groups of size $18$ and one lab group of size $14$, whereas if the four members are all assigned to different labs groups, then the other $284$ people have to be partitioned into $12$ lab groups of size $18$ and $4$ lab groups of size $17$. There are other scenarios as well.

Comment: Thank you so much Will!